# Question about the uniqueness of solutions?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was working on a few practice problems for my applied ordinary differential equations class and I was stumped on a really simple intro problem.

If we are told that a DFQ has the following form:

$$\frac{du}{dx} = f(u,x)$$

Is there any way to infer the number of solutions it has? Can $u(x) = x^2$ and $u(x) = x^3$ both be solutions? I'm thinking not, since usually a DFQ with multiple solutions has all solutions differ by a constant, not something with the dependent variable.

Are there standard rules for this?

Any help is extremely appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get both $u=x^2$ and $u=x^3$ as solutions if the exponent is the integration constant, that is, the general solution is $u=x^C$. Isolating $C$ and taking the derivative results in
$$
C=\frac{\ln u}{\ln x}\implies 0=\frac{u'}{u\ln x}-\frac{\ln u}{x(\ln x)^2}
$$
so that the corresponding differential equation is
$$
u'=\frac{u\ln u}{x\ln x}.
$$

---

You can also take other forms of interpolation like $u=Cx^2+(1-C)x^3$ so that
$$
C=\frac{u-x^3}{x^2-x^3}\implies 0=\frac{u'-3x^2}{x^2-x^3}-\frac{(u-x^3)(2x-3x^2)}{(x^2-x^3)^2}
$$
leading to the differential equation
$$
u'=3x^2+\frac{(2-3x)(u-x^3)}{x(1-x)}
$$

etc.

Comment: That makes so much sense. Thank you! I don't believe we've learned about interpolation yet, but I'm sure we will.